# Почему локальный кэш на сервере плохо?

Tags: highload, нагрузка

Я новичок по части высоконагруженных систем, и если мой вопрос покажется глупым или я буду путаться в терминах, заранее прошу прощения.

Я никак не могу понять, почему высоконагруженные приложения избегают кэшировать данные локально на сервере?
Вместо этого используются кэширующие сервисы по типу `memcached` или `redis`.

Типичная архитектура нагруженного приложения такая: клиент посылает запрос к серверу, сервер принимает этот запрос и сначала идет за данными в кэширущий сервис (`Redis`, `memchached`), и если там нет данных, то уже тогда идет в базу данных.

Просто для это меня это странно - почему нельзя кэшировать на самом сервере и не бегать за данными в `Memcached` (тратить кучу времени на подключение, потом получение этих данных по сети).
Несмотря на это, большинство высоконагруженных проектов работает именно так и у них нету проблем со скоростью и нагрузкой, но все же меня мучает вопрос почему они не используют локальный кэш.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что для высоконагруженных систем вы забыли еще один элемент - балансировщик нагрузки.

1. Клиент подключается не к серверу, а к балансировщику нагрузки
2. Балансировщик находит оптимальный сервер для выполнения запроса и передает запрос ему
3. Исполнитель запроса обращается к **общему** кешу и ищет данные там.
4. Если не находит, то идет в базу

Получается, что два различных сервера имеют общий кеш. При локальном кеше вы можете незначительно ускорить выполнение первого запроса (когда кеш пустой), но затормозите всю систему, Т.к. каждый исполнитель вынужден будет накапливать свой собственный кеш.

Comment: а почему нельзя размазать кэшируемые данные по серверам, сказать серверу 1 ты будешь кэшировать пользователей с 1 по 1000, а ты сервер 2 будешь кэшировать пользователей 1000 по 2000 итд и тогда каждый сервер не будет вынужден накапливать кэш, а кэшировать только то что ему сказали, а пользователь будет знать какая информация где закэширована и не трогать другие сервера. Или это тоже плохой выход так как может привести к разбалансировке нагрузки?

Comment: и еще один вопрос вы сказали, что балансировщик нагрузки выбирает наиболее оптимальный сервер для выполнения запроса, как я понимаю речь идет о сервере который менее нагружен запросами, но тогда вопрос какая разница к какому серверу  давать на выполнение запрос если все эти сервера в любом случае бегают за данными в единый кэш, и встают в очередь за данными друг за другом, нельзя сразу дать все эти задачи этому самому кэшу, который к тому же будет выполнять и роль сервера, без всяких дополнительных посредников которые  только тратят время на запрос по сети, исправьте меня если я ошибаюсь

Comment: @cvxbcvbsdfsddfgdfg `находит оптимальный сервер для выполнения запроса` допустим, что у вас три сервера. И системой в данный момент пользуются 600 клиентов. Но из первой тысячи. Тогда вместо того, чтобы разбросать на каждый сервер по 200 клиентов все 600 выстроятся в очередь к первому серверу. А остальные сервера будут отдыхать. А есть еще данные, не относящиеся к пользователям. Их как кешировать?

Comment: @cvxbcvbsdfsddfgdfg это не всегда наименее загруженный. Это может быть сервер с минимальным пингом, например. Ну и кто вам сказал, что кеширующий сервер нельзя поставить за свой балансировщик?

Comment: ну так, в этом то и дело, они в любом случае выстроятся в очередь ведь у них единая точка доступа к данным(единый кэш). И не важно обслуживают их один сервер или 3, в первом случае к кэшу за данными пойдет один сервер а во втором сразу 3 и все  равно все 3 сервера будут стоять в очереди за данными. И так и так получается очередь

Comment: а насчет данных несвязанных с клиентами, можно допустим поставить отдельный сервак, и сказать клиентам, что если нужны данные несвязанные с клиентами идите к такому-то серверу.

Comment: @cvxbcvbsdfsddfgdfg еще раз - кеш сидит за своим балансировщиком. Т.е. это отдельная многосерверная система. Кроме того, считается, что достать данные из кеша на порядок быстрее чем вычислить заново. Если это не так, то имеет место архитектурная ошибка в кеширующей системе

Comment: Я вроде начинаю понимать, то есть кэш тоже принимает и отвечает на запросы асинхронно, и может обслуживать несколько серверов одновременно, им не нужно выстраиваться в очередь за данными, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @cvxbcvbsdfsddfgdfg да. Кроме того один сервер может послать несколько **параллельных** запросов к кешу для получения различных данных